# WSO2 EMM - Manage data to wrapping them in multi page

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have added new report to EMM, but as the report data recorde are too much, I would like to wrap them in multiple pages like configuration tab (users, roles and policies), How can I fix this or how it works for those tabs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 EMM is built on top of bootstrap 2. You can add Bootstrap tabs as mention in following doc and have multiple tabs on your page

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs

**Edit:**

WSO2 EMM 1.1.0 is built on top of a Jaggery MVC framework.

Create a report by adding a function to emm/controller/reports.js. This is a controller and you can use modules to retrieve data to the controller. see devices_complience function for example in the following file

https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/master/modules/apps/emm/controller/reports.js

Add the corresponding view file to emm/views/reports

Eg: https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/master/modules/apps/emm/views/reports/devices_complience.hbs

Add a link to your report in the emm/views/reports/index.hbs file

If you need to have additional java-script functions you can add them to emm/client/js/reports/reports.js file

Comment: I need to broke data in multipage like roles tab which is show 10 record per page.

Comment: I find these two javascript files \emm\modules\paginate and emm\assets\jqueryext\datatables\jquery.datatables which are related to paging. but I don't know how to use them

Comment: Thanks, I already add the report to EMM, the problem was paging the recorde on its view.

Comment: pagination is handled by the page automatically from the js file emm/client/js/reports/reports.js. It uses  j-query data tables. so you can control the records count, sorting from the data table values. please check the corresponding data tables parameters for datatables version that is used in EMM.

Answer (score 0):

I should edit "Carbone_Home\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\emm\client\js\reports.js" file to managing record on table.

```
"sDom":"t"
```

to

```
"sDom":"<'row-fluid't<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>"
```

and for setting number of record per page I should set this :

```
"iDisplayLength": 10,
```

which uses emm\assets\jqueryext\datatables\jquery.datatables.